# How to use case when then SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, case

I'm trying to count how many transaction each day per month from table. I have query like this :

```
SELECT namarss,
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-01' then count(namarss) else '' end as "01",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-02' then count(namarss) else '' end as "02",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-03' then count(namarss) else '' end as "03",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-04' then count(namarss) else '' end as "04",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-05' then count(namarss) else '' end as "05",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-06' then count(namarss) else '' end as "06",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-07' then count(namarss) else '' end as "07",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-08' then count(namarss) else '' end as "08",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-09' then count(namarss) else '' end as "09",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-10' then count(namarss) else '' end as "10",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-11' then count(namarss) else '' end as "11",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-12' then count(namarss) else '' end as "12",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-13' then count(namarss) else '' end as "13",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-14' then count(namarss) else '' end as "14",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-15' then count(namarss) else '' end as "15",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-16' then count(namarss) else '' end as "16",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-17' then count(namarss) else '' end as "17",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-18' then count(namarss) else '' end as "18",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-19' then count(namarss) else '' end as "19",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-20' then count(namarss) else '' end as "20",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-21' then count(namarss) else '' end as "21",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-22' then count(namarss) else '' end as "22",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-23' then count(namarss) else '' end as "23",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-24' then count(namarss) else '' end as "24",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-25' then count(namarss) else '' end as "25",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-26' then count(namarss) else '' end as "26",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-27' then count(namarss) else '' end as "27",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-28' then count(namarss) else '' end as "28",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-29' then count(namarss) else '' end as "29",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-30' then count(namarss) else '' end as "30",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-31' then count(namarss) else '' end as "31"
FROM mcutrpendaftaran
group by namarss, tanggal_daftar
```

and the result is like this :

[image]

but I want the result show like this :

[image]

what should I do to fix it ? Thank you :)

Comment: please update your table definition

Comment: I guess your requirement is to **get count for each namarss for each day**. Better adopt the simpler query (`group by namarass , day and get the count thereby)`. Later do the pivoting in your application level.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove field `tanggal_daftar` from `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT namarss,
       case when tanggal_daftar = '2016-06-01' then 1 end as "01",
       case when tanggal_daftar = '2016-06-02' then 1 end as "02",
       case when tanggal_daftar = '2016-06-03' then 1 end as "03",
       case when tanggal_daftar = '2016-06-04' then 1 end as "04",
       case when tanggal_daftar = '2016-06-05' then 1 end as "05",
       ...

FROM mcutrpendaftaran
group by namarss
```

The above query should give you one record per `namarss` value.

Comment: if I remove tanggal_daftar, the result will show '6' in date 2 @GiorgosBetsos

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
group by namarss, tanggal_daftar
```

to

```
 group by namarss
```

and change

```
count(namarss) to count(tanggal_daftar) everywhere
```

EDIT:

This works, but it's ugly:

```
    select namarss, sum([01]) [01], sum([02]) [02], sum([03]) [03], sum([04]) [04]
from (
SELECT namarss,
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-01' then count(tanggal_daftar) else '' end as "01",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-02' then count(tanggal_daftar) else '' end as "02",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-03' then count(tanggal_daftar) else '' end as "03",
case(tanggal_daftar) when '2016-06-04' then count(tanggal_daftar) else '' end as "04"
FROM mcutrpendaftaran
group by namarss, tanggal_daftar) A group by namarss
```

I haven't tested this but even if this query works, it's far from optimized. Supplying some sample data from the `mcutrpendaftaran` table would really help.

Comment: the result is the same , no differences @AshwinNair